# Android not recognizing my device

Tags: android, eclipse, device, adb

I have already installed the drivers. I can transfer files from my Tablet to the PC.

Debug Mode is on, but adb devices and eclipse are not finding it.

It's a chinese tablet (=/) running version 2.2.

My PC is a Windows 7.

Already tried restarting ADB, but it didn't work.

Anyone knows what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure You've installed the ADB drivers for Your device or just the general device drivers? If not, check out the "Naked drivers" package on xda-developers. There are most of the important drivers.
Does Your adb interface recognize Your device when You type

```
adb devices
```

?

Here's a really nice tutorial:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2139767

Comment: When I type `adb devices`, nothing appears.

It shows "List of devices attached", and only this.

Comment: Is your device regognized as ADB device in Your devicemanager?

Comment: Will do. Thanks for answering me, I'll let you know if this tutorial helped. I'm a newbie, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't install using those drivers. It says it's not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I've for some reason always had issues with ADB drivers, even when using the correct driver for the device, it says its installed but device manager says it can start for some reason. The way I've found to fix it which has always worked for me, not matter the device is to install pda Net on your PC. Its purpose is really to allow you to tether your device to your PC but it installs the ADB driver without issue.

You can find the software at http://pdanet.co/

Comment: Didn't work... nothing works. What the hell. I don't know what to do anymore!

Comment: If you look in Device Manager does it show the adb device or does it have an exclamation mark. Also does the phone show the debug icon in the notification bar. I have seen it that sometimes the phone connects to the PC for standard media transfer but debug doesn't work and the PC and the phone both need to be restarted